# How to sync two different repositories in Git

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have one local git repository set up for our team. There is another git repository set up for a remote team( they are some freelancers ). My problem is I want to sync the live server code in which the freelancers are making changes, with my local git and push the latest code to server. How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't it more simple to push the modifications from the freelancers repo and then you'll be able to fetch you repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [add the freelancers repository as "remote"](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote) then `git fetch` from it to your local repository. Then you can merge the references from the freelancers to the work from your core team and push to the work to their repository.

For example something like this :

```
git remote add team {githubofteam}
git remote add free {githuboffreelancers}
git fetch team
git checkout -b master team/master
git fetch free
git merge free/master
git push team master
```